# How to use heading tags in html when printing a text using a variable in php

Tags: php, variables

I have this code.

PHP coded

```
<body>
    <?php
        $var="PHP TUTORIAL";
        echo $var;
    ?>  
    <p>PHP is a hypertext preprocessor</p>
</body>
```

Im wondering how I could use the  tag in html when printing `$var`.

Can you use html codes inside `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: *"Im wondering how I could use the tag in html"* - Can you elaborate on that? as in what...? `.html` extension? on local machine/hosted?

Comment: *"Can you use html codes inside <?php ... ?>"* - Did you try it??

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php - https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php - http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/ - Stack isn't a school, nor an academy. There are ample tutorials out there and your question is too broad. **This is both PHP/HTML 101.** When you have a ***real*** problem with code, then come back. We'll be more than happy to help. Till then, this question's a "how-to" and not a "my code won't work" type of question.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can! All the PHP output will be sent and handled by the browser, including the HTML within.

```
<body>
    <?php echo "<h1>This is a PHP header 1!</h1>"; ?>
    <h2>This is an HTML header 2!</h2>
    <?php echo "<h3>This is a PHP header 3"; ?> that's also half HTML!</h3>
    <?php echo "<h4>This is a variable: ".$var."</h4>"; ?>
</body>
```

This will output in the browser like so:

```
<body>
    <h1>This is a PHP header 1!</h1>
    <h2>This is an HTML header 2!</h2>
    <h3>This is a PHP header 3 that's also half HTML!</h3>
    <h4>This is a variable: foobar</h4>
</body>
```

Comment: omg.....!! it printed :)... thankkkkk yooouuu!!!

Comment: @CamilleTea You're welcome. I've added an `h4` example that shows how to include variables too.

Comment: can i call a variable in the title tag? like for example, <title> $var </title> "$var" will show up but I want the "PHP TUTORIAL" to show up.

Comment: You can write `<title><?php echo $var; ?></title>` or `echo "<title>".$var."</title>"; ?> and it will output what you're after.